# Part of jQuery not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is as follows:

When I test this, the part marked as NOT BEING EXECUTED is not executed.
The rest of the code prior to that point works fine, but after that line nothing happens.

Am I missing something?  I'm running Firefox with firebug and I can see that the vars (enrolled, groupcontracting and thirdparty) are being defined as 1 or 0.. but they don't see to be visible to the code below the 'NOT BEING EXECUTED' line.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#restofform').css('display', 'none');
    $('#pharmdata').css('display', 'none');
    $('#form_bottom').css('display', 'none');
    $('#nextsteps').css('display', 'none');
    $('#group_status_message').css('display', 'none');
    $("#Affiliation").css('display', 'none');
    $("#affiliation_note").css('display', 'none');
    $("#AffiliationLabel").css('display', 'none');
    $("#affilitation").css('display', 'none');

    var enrolled;
    var groupcontracting;
    var thirdparty;

    $('#UserNumber').keyup(function check_enrollment() {

        //get the userid
        var userid = $('#UserNumber').val();
        var input_length = $("#UserNumber").val().length;

        function populate(frm, data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('[id=' + key + ']', frm).val(value);
            });
        }

        if (input_length >= 7) {
            //network enrollment check
            var enlink = "enrollment_check.php?userid =" + userid;
            var gpclink = "group_contracting_check.php?userid =" + userid;
            var bncdlink = "thirdparty_check.php?userid =" + userid;
            $.getJSON(enlink, function (result) {
                console.log(result);

                if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                    //show that the pharmacy is not enrolled
                    $('#enroll_status').addClass('badge badge-inverse');
                    $('#enroll_status').html('Not Enrolled');
                    enrolled = '0';
                    console.log(enrolled);

                } else if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                    //show that the pharmacy is enrolled
                    $('#enroll_status').addClass('badge badge-success');
                    $('#enroll_status').html('Enrolled');
                    enrolled = '1';
                    console.log(enrolled);
                }
            });
            // end of network enrollment check  

            // group contracting affiliation check
            $.getJSON(gpclink, function (gcresult) {
                console.log(gcresult);

                if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(gcresult)) {
                    //show that the username is available
                    $('#group_status').addClass('badge badge-success');
                    $('#group_status').html('Group Affiliated');
                    groupcontracting = '1';
                    console.log(groupcontracting);

                } else if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(gcresult)) {
                    //show that the username is NOT available
                    groupcontracting = '0';
                    console.log(groupcontracting);
                }
            });
            // end of group contracting check

            // third party contractual relationship check
            $.getJSON(bncdlink, function (bdresult) {
                console.log(bdresult);

                if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(bdresult)) {
                    //show that the username is available
                    $('#thirdparty_status').addClass('badge badge-success');
                    $('#thirdparty_status').html('Third Party');
                    thirdparty = '1';
                    console.log(thirdparty);

                } else if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(bdresult)) {
                    //show that the username is NOT available
                    thirdparty = '0';
                    console.log(thirdparty);
                }
            });
            //end of third party check


            // ***********THIS PART IS NOT BEING EXECUTED *************
            // check to see what the variables are set to and display accordingly

            if ((enrolled == '0') && (groupcontracting == '0') && (thirdparty == '0')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('0');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('0');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('0');
                //show and hide appropriate parts of forms
                $('#restofform').css('display', '');
                $('#form_bottom').css('display', '');
                $('#pharmdata').css('display', 'none');
                $('#nextsteps').css('display', '');
                $('#form_continue').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#form_continue').css('display', 'none');
                $('#form_enroll').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#form_enroll').css('display', '');
                // enable form fields
                $('#FirstName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#LastName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#EmailAddress').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#HomePhone').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#FaxNumber').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#CompanyName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#Role').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#Comments').attr('disabled', false);
                //display third party message since the Pharmacy will need to sign with them.
                $('#steps').append('<li>This would be the third party statement, letting the pharmacy know that the third party will be contacting them.</li>');

            } else if ((enrolled == '0') && (groupcontracting == '1') && (thirdparty == '0')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('0');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('1');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('0');
                //show and hide appropriate parts of forms
                $('#restofform').css('display', '');
                $('#form_bottom').css('display', '');
                $('#pharmdata').css('display', 'none');
                $('#nextsteps').css('display', '');
                $('#form_continue').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#form_continue').css('display', 'none');
                $('#form_enroll').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#form_enroll').css('display', '');
                // enable form fields
                $('#FirstName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#LastName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#EmailAddress').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#HomePhone').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#FaxNumber').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#CompanyName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#Role').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#Comments').attr('disabled', false);
                //display third party message since the Pharmacy will need to sign with them.
                $('#steps').append('<li>This would be the third partystatement, letting the pharmacy know that the third party will be contacting them.</li>');
                // show message to Pharmacy that they can enroll, but their group contracting entity will enroll them in products
                $('#steps').append('<li>As a pharmacy currently affiliated with a group contracting entity, you will be able to enroll in the network, but enrollment in the Preferred Network will be handled by your group contracting entity.</li>');


            } else if ((enrolled == '0') && (groupcontracting == '0') && (thirdparty == '1')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('0');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('0');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('1');
                //show and hide appropriate parts of forms
                $('#restofform').css('display', '');
                $('#form_bottom').css('display', '');
                $('#pharmdata').css('display', 'none');
                $('#nextsteps').css('display', '');
                $('#form_continue').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#form_continue').css('display', 'none');
                $('#form_enroll').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#form_enroll').css('display', '');
                // enable form fields
                $('#FirstName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#LastName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#EmailAddress').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#HomePhone').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#FaxNumber').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#CompanyName').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#Role').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#Comments').attr('disabled', false);

            } else if ((enrolled == '1') && (groupcontracting == '0') && (thirdparty == '0')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('1');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('0');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('0');
                //show & populate and hide appropriate parts of forms
                $('#restofform').css('display', 'none');
                $('#pharmdata').css('display', '');
                $('#form_bottom').css('display', '');
                $('#nextsteps').css('display', '');
                $('#form_continue').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#form_continue').css('display', '');
                $('#form_enroll').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#form_enroll').css('display', 'none');
                populate('#pharmdata', result); // set as the div the fields are in and NOT the form
                // disable form fields
                $('#FirstName').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#LastName').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#EmailAddress').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#HomePhone').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#FaxNumber').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#CompanyName').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#Role').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#Comments').attr('disabled', true);
                // show message to Pharmacy that they should check their info before proceding
                $('#steps').append('<li>If any of your information needs to be updated, please click <a href="mailto:network@company.com">here</a> to email our network support team.</li>');
                //display third partymessage since the Pharmacy will need to sign with them.
                $('#steps').append('<li>This would be the third party statement, letting the pharmacy know that the third party will be contacting them.</li>');

            } else if ((enrolled == '1') && (groupcontracting == '1') && (thirdparty == '0')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('1');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('1');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('0');
                // show message to Pharmacy that they are good to go and have nothing further to do.
                $('#group_status_message').html('<p class="content-p">As a pharmacy both currently a Network Member and affiliated with a group contracting entity, no further steps are required. You will be enrolled into the Preferred Network by your group contracting entity.</p>');

            } else if ((enrolled == '1') && (groupcontracting == '1') && (thirdparty == '1')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('1');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('1');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('1');
                // show message to Pharmacy that they are good to go and have nothing further to do.
                $('#group_status_message').html('<p class="content-p">As a pharmacy both currently a Network Member and affiliated with a group contracting entity, no further steps are required. You will be enrolled into the Preferred Network by your group contracting entity.</p>');

            } else if ((enrolled == '1') && (groupcontracting == '0') && (thirdparty == '1')) {

                // set hidden fields 
                $('input[name=enrolled]').val('1');
                $('input[name=groupcontracting]').val('0');
                $('input[name=thirdparty]').val('1');
                //show & populate and hide appropriate parts of forms
                $('#restofform').css('display', 'none');
                $('#pharmdata').css('display', '');
                $('#form_bottom').css('display', '');
                $('#nextsteps').css('display', '');
                $('#form_continue').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#form_continue').css('display', '');
                $('#form_enroll').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#form_enroll').css('display', 'none');
                populate('#pharmdata', result); // set as the div the fields are in and NOT the form
                // disable form fields
                $('#FirstName').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#LastName').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#EmailAddress').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#HomePhone').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#FaxNumber').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#CompanyName').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#Role').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#Comments').attr('disabled', true);
                // show message to Pharmacy that they should check their info before proceding
                $('#steps').append('<li>If any of your information needs to be updated, please click <a href="mailto:network@company.com">here</a> to email our network support team.</li>');

            }

        }
    });
    // end of 3rd party contract check
    // end of all checks



}); // document.ready()
```

Comment: You might want to try cutting it back to a minimal working example... I can't believe that all that code is necessary to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Not sure whether it is just a result of you pasting the code into the editor, but your indentation is pretty bad - and makes working out what is going very difficult

Comment: Is it not being executed (did you set a breakpoint?) or is that the variables aren't set yet because the preceding statements are asynchronous?

Comment: Before the 'not executed' line, run this: `alert(enrolled == '0' && groupcontracting == '0' && thirdparty== '0')` - does it say true or false? If false, one or more of the vars does not contain what you think it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you say isn't running is failing simply because those `$.getJSON` function calls are asynchronous.

When the JavaScript engine gets to that first `if (...)` statement, none of the `$.getJSON` methods have returned values yet, so jQuery happily evaluates that to "false" and skips right over it, like it's supposed to.

Try wrapping that block of code in an [$.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) wrapper:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    // this code will run after all AJAX events have completed
});
```

Comment: Blazemonger! Thank you! That did the trick. It's all working perfectly now.

To those above, yes the pasting of the code messed up the indenting. I'm very particular about code indention.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting enrolled, groupcontracting, and thirdparty variables to be in global scope, you should define them as such (i.e. outside the onready function).  You also might want to explicitly set the values to '0' if that is intended to be their default value.